# Roblox plays my sound repeatedly on touch, causing Studio to crash

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm struggling to find a way to make this code work. Basically, what this is supposed to do, is create a clone of the parent `Sound` for each `Position` in the `Positions` folder and play them, and then play the subtitle sequence on the in-game screen.

Here's the entire code for the script, since it's quite small (with some added comments for context):

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players");
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService");

local col = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Collision", 30);
local audioPositions = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Positions"):GetChildren();
local voiceline = script.Parent;
local subtitleSequence = script.Parent:WaitForChild("SubtitleSequence"):GetChildren();

--[[Contains a function that creates an audio clone by passing the audio to clone
and a target parent which is used on this script (and as far as I know, it works)]]
local audioFunc = require(game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").__AUDIO);
--[[Used to return the GameGui Subtitles text used to play out the subtitle sequence
(again, as far as I know, it works)]]
local gameUIFunc = require(game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").__GAME_UI);

local touched = false;

local function RunSubtitleSequence()
    for i, subtitle in pairs(subtitleSequence) do
        local duration = subtitle:WaitForChild("Duration");
        
        local subtitleText = gameUIFunc.returnSubtitlesTextObject(Players.LocalPlayer);
        if subtitleText == nil then return; end;
        subtitleText.Text = subtitle.Value;
        wait(duration.Value);
    end;
    gameUIFunc.returnSubtitlesTextObject(Players.LocalPlayer).Text = "";
end;

col.Touched:Connect(function()
    RunService.Heartbeat:Wait();
    if touched then
        return;
    end;
    touched = true;
    RunService.Heartbeat:Wait();
    for i, audioPosition in pairs(audioPositions) do
        audioFunc.createSound(voiceline, audioPosition);
    end;
    RunService.Heartbeat:Wait();
    task.spawn(function()
        RunSubtitleSequence();
    end);
end);
```

And here's the structure surrounding the script and all the needed objects:

```
|----Sound [SOUND]
|----|----Positions [FOLDER]
|----|----|----Position [PART]
|----|----|----Position [PART]
|----|----|----Position [PART]
|----|----SubtitleSequence [FOLDER]
|----|----|----0 [STRINGVALUE]
|----|----|----|----Duration [INTVALUE]
|----|----|----1 [STRINGVALUE]
|----|----|----|----Duration [INTVALUE]
|----|----VoicelineTrigger [LOCALSCRIPT]
|----|----Collision [PART]
```

I debounced the script by default and since that didn't work, I tried to do some things that I thought could help:
-I've tried adding `RunService.Heartbeat:Wait();` to wait for the next frame, didn't work.
-I tried putting the subtitle sequence in a coroutine with `task.spawn(func)` and it did not work either.

I can't really tell what's going wrong here

EDIT: This is the stack trace when booting up the game:

```
  19:52:46.208  Infinite yield possible on 'ReplicatedStorage.__SCRIPTS.__VOICE_LINES:WaitForChild("Positions")'  -  Studio
  19:52:46.208  Stack Begin  -  Studio
  19:52:46.209  Script 'ReplicatedStorage.__SCRIPTS.__VOICE_LINES.VoicelineTrigger', Line 5  -  Studio - VoicelineTrigger:5
  19:52:46.209  Stack End  -  Studio
```

EDIT 2: Probably irrelevant but the stack trace is full of other "Infinite yield possible" notices but that's due to bad performance (they're just core ROBLOX modules n stuff)
Is there any way to fix that

EDIT 3: I tried what Ivan said and the game still crashes. Here's the code I changed (the rest is still left the same):

```lua
--.......
local touched = false;

local function RunSubtitles()
    if touched then
        return;
    end;
    touched = true;

    for i, audioPosition in pairs(audioPositions) do
        audioFunc.createSound(voiceline, audioPosition);
    end;

    task.spawn(function()
        RunSubtitleSequence();
    end);
    col:Destroy();
end

col.Touched:Once(RunSubtitles);
```

Something I noticed is that sometimes it works properly, it actually executes the function once, and sometimes it doesn't, a.k.a. it executes the function over and over until Studio crashes. I'm not sure why-

I'm wondering if it's the script being parented to a sound? I've never done that before and stuff worked mighty fine so I'll see if changing that up works. It could also be the fact that the script isn't really parented to the Sound when the game loads as I have a script replication system to ease the modification of scripts by editing a single one and then replicating it (yes I'm too lazy to use packages they're too complicated). (The script starts as disabled and then gets enabled by the script replication script)

EDIT 4: The script parented to a Sound was not the problem it seems. I'm still stuck.

Comment: Apologies if I'm editing this too much, I'm not used to using StackOverflow so I'm not really sure if it's wrong or not-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND OUT THE PROBLEM! I was creating multiple copies of the same audio object over and over (as I stated on the first version of the code, the functions I use to generate sounds clone it entirely) so the children were being cloned, including the collision and script, which caused to an endless recursion.
The solution was as easy as replacing the audio file for a Part and reference the voiceline without any children (and in my case, I used the part for collisions as well).
sobbing and crying it was so simple

Comment: also a big thank you to the one person helping me here who told me to use the debugger i wouldn't have found out without it :D

Comment: :) good thing it was finally solved

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as-to why you're using

```lua
RunService.Heartbeat:Wait();
```

on the first line.
Roblox events work nearly concurrently, meaning once an event has been called, it can be called again within the time it takes for the other event's call to have been processed by your script. It would mean it will create a lot of event calls, running your script an equal amount of times up until

```lua
touched = true;
```

is reached, though all the other already running threads executing your code are already running.

A better approach would be to only have it execute the code once, e.g.:

```lua
local function onTouch()
    ...
end

col.Touched:Once(onTouch)
```

And only when you're fully aware the code has been executed and do want it to listen for the event again, hook the event listener.

Comment: And most likely, those infinite yield lines on roblox core scripts/modules is because of your CPU being too slow processing those scripts. You could use :WaitForChild(NAME, math.huge) to wait infinitely.

Comment: The reason why I used Heartbeat:Wait() was purely just to see if that fixed the issue. Also, this did not work unfortunately. I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Have you tried using studio's debugger? It could show you where the stack trace stops or has issues running the script and where it causes it to run multiple times. Have you also properly whitelisted/blacklisted parts that shouldn't activate the script? For example the ground.

Comment: How would I use the built-in debugger? I have never used it and I can't really find any official documentation, if you could redirect me to any in-depth tutorials about it I'd appreciate it. And no, I don't think I properly white-listed that which I think is the cause, I'll check it and report back

Comment: Ok, so, filtering the player doesn't work either. I'm going to try the debugger now, found out how to use it

Comment: Judging by the debugger, it seems that the problem is the script completely glossing over the if statement that checks if `touched` is equal to true (`if touched then return; end;`)